# Is there a picker to show audio/image/video in ios app?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I understand it is possible to browse/pick image and video files using `UIImagePickerController`.

I understand it is possible to browse/pick audio using `MPMediaPickerController`.

Is there a picker which shows image, video and audio files at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in iOS, where you can show image, video and audio files in a single picker view. because all are the different mechanism.

**UIImagePickerController** - controller that manages the system interfaces for taking pictures, recording movies, and choosing items from the user's media library.

**MPMediaPickerController** view controller that provides a graphical interface for selecting media items.

If you want to achieve these two in a single picker, then you have to create an abstract class and add that feature with both MPMediaPickerController & UIImagePickerController and provide a protocol to conform to those methods. Which takes a little high time.